# Find all the combinations, by eliminating one ar a time until list is empty and what is the best Data Structure to process list in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, data-structures

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Combinations are:

```
[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]

[2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 2]

[1], [2], [3], [4]
```

Code:

```
from itertools import combinations

a = [1, 2, 3, 4]

list1 = list()

b = combinations(a, len(a)-1)

for i in b:

    list1.append(list(i))

list2 = list()


while len(list1) != 0:

    temp = list1.pop()

    comb = combinations(temp, len(temp)-1)

    for i in comb:

        if list(i) not in list2:

            print(list(i))

            list2.append(list(i))
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct about using [**`itertools.combinations`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), but you need to loop through several possible lengths to produce your final output.  Finally, I used [**`itertools.chain.from_iterable`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten the resulting list:

```
>>> from itertools import chain, combinations
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(combinations(a, i) for i in range(1, len(a))))
[(1,),
 (2,),
 (3,),
 (4,),
 (1, 2),
 (1, 3),
 (1, 4),
 (2, 3),
 (2, 4),
 (3, 4),
 (1, 2, 3),
 (1, 2, 4),
 (1, 3, 4),
 (2, 3, 4)]
```

If you are dead set on the elements being lists, store the result, and use **`map`**

```
list(map(list, res))
```